# How can I connect my Steam Link directly to my Windows PC?

Tags: wired-networking, steam, steam-link

I recently bought a Steam Link to play my PC games on TV, but playing over WiFi hasn't been a great experience, with random hiccups, delays and dropped frames.

[I had read in on Steam discussions](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/0/343785574519542460/) that it should be possible to hook it up through a CAT5 Ethernet cable, but how can I get it working?

Answer (score 3):

It was incredibly simple:

1. Attach an ethernet cable to the Steam Link and the PC.
2. Go into the PC's Network Connections screen, and right-click on the internet connection you wish to share with the Steam Link.
   [image: WiFi properties]
3. Under the "Sharing" tab, enable the option for "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection".
4. Select the Ethernet network connection the Steam Link is connected to and press OK.
   [image: Internet connection sharing]

Steam Link should now pick up the wired connection over connecting through WiFi and work much more reliably!

Comment: Have you used a crossover network cable or a regular one?

Comment: Just a regular network cable.